# PHP: How to properly format 19 drinks

Tags: php

This is my first time using stackoverflow. With that out of the way, I seem to have a little php problem. It's about outputting the code of 19 drinks. With my current code, it outputs the following:

```
19 drinks can serve odd number of guests.   
You take 19 down from 19...  
18 drinks can serve even number of guests.   
You take 18 down from 19...  
17 drinks can serve odd number of guests.   
You take 17 down from 19...  
16 drinks can serve odd number of guests.
```

When instead it should output the following:

```
19 drinks can serve odd number of guests. 
You take 1 down from 19...
18 drinks can serve even number of guests. 
You take 2 down from 19...
17 drinks can serve odd number of guests. 
You take 3 down from 19...
16 drinks can serve odd number of guests.
```

Here is the actual code.

```
<?php

    $drinks= 19;

    for($drinks= 19; $drinks>= 1; $drinks--) 
    {

        if ($drinks % 2) 
        {
            echo '<br />';
            echo $drinks. ' drinks can serve odd number of guests. ';
            echo '<br />';
            echo 'You take ' . $drinks. ' down from 19...';
            echo '<br />';
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<br />';
            echo $drinks. ' drinks can serve even number of guests. ';
            echo '<br />';
            echo 'You take ' .  $drinks. ' down from 19...';
            echo '<br />';
            continue;
        }
    }
?>
```

I'm seem to be in a stump. What sort of issues can I properly deal with this?

Comment: replace `'You take ' .  $drinks. ' down from 19...';` with `'You take ' .  (19-$drinks+1). ' down from 19...';`

Comment: correct format;-https://eval.in/665671

Comment: Read the Book here: http://99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-php-1825.html  no oop version

Comment: Thank you all for the information. It is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to define number of drinks only once:

```
<?php

  $drinkNr=19;
  for ($drinks= $drinkNr; $drinks> 0; $drinks--) 
  {
    :
    // now you can do the text
    echo 'You take ' . ($drinkNr - $drinks + 1) . ' down from ' . $drinkNr . '..';
```

Answer (score 0):

Jeez.
Here's a short, easy code to do this:

```
<?php

$total = 19;
$i = 1;
for ($c=$total;$c>0;$c--) {
    $output = (($c % 2) == 1) ? $c.' drinks can serve odd number of guests' : $c.' drinks can serve even number of guests';
    $output .= ($i != $total) ?'<br>You take '.$i.' down from '.$total.'...' : '';
    echo $output.'<br>';
    $i++;
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$drinks_total = 19;

for($drinks_taken = 1; $drinks_taken <= $drinks_total; $drinks_taken++) 
{

    if ($drinks_taken % 2) 
    {
        $html = '
            <br />
            %d drinks can serve even number of guests
            <br />
            You take %d down from %d...
            <br />
        ';
    }
    else
    {
       $html = '
            <br />
            %d drinks can serve odd number of guests
            <br />
            You take %d down from %d...
            <br />
        ';

    }

    echo sprintf($html,$drinks_total - $drinks_taken, $drinks_taken, $drinks_total);
}
```

Comment: Downvoted, could you add some explanation for the code?